# Nested object to hierarchical object list

Tags: c#

I have a C# type to generate `Layer` `SubLayer`:

```
public class Layer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And simulated a list with a `Db` class:

```
public static class Db
    {
        public static IList<Layer> GetLayers()
        {
            return new List<Layer>
                   {
                       new Layer{Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "First Layer" },
                       new Layer{Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "First SubLayer1" },
                       new Layer{Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "First SubLayer2" },
                       new Layer{Id = 4, ParentId = 1, Name = "First SubLayer3" },
                       new Layer{Id = 5, ParentId = 0, Name = "Second Layer" },
                       new Layer{Id = 6, ParentId = 5, Name = "Second SubLayer1" },
                       new Layer{Id = 7, ParentId = 5, Name = "Second SubLayer2" },
                       new Layer{Id = 8, ParentId = 7, Name = "Sub -3" }
                   };
        }
    }
```

I want to get a serialized JSON object, so I created a service class to generate and changed the `Layer` class:

```
public class Layer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Layer> ChildLayers { get; set; }

    public Layer()
    {
        ChildLayers = new List<Layer>();
    }
}

public class LayerService
{
    public IList<Layer> GetLayers()
    {
        IList<Layer> data = Db.GetLayers();

        IList<Layer> hierarcy = new List<Layer>();

        foreach (var layer in data)
        {
            var layer1 = layer;

            var sublayers = data.Where(i => i.ParentId == layer1.Id && i.ParentId !=0);

            var enumerable = sublayers as Layer[] ?? sublayers.ToArray();

            if(enumerable.Any() && layer.ParentId ==0)
                hierarcy.Add(layer);

            foreach (var sublayer in enumerable)
            {
                layer.ChildLayers.Add(sublayer);    
            }
        }

        return hierarcy;
    }
}
```

But this `LayerService` code is ugly. Is there any practical way with Linq or else? Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> var sublayers = data.Where(i => i.ParentId == layer1.Id && i.ParentId !=0);
> ```

you should let the operators some room to breathe. Adding a space after `=` makes your code more readable.

**Bug alert**

In the above query you are filtering for `i.ParentId != 0` and later on you have the condition `&& layer.ParentId ==0` so your `hierarchy` wil remain empty.

---

> ```
> var enumerable = sublayers as Layer[] ?? sublayers.ToArray();
> ```

This makes me just wonder. What sense does it have to convert the `IEnumerable<Layer>` to an array if the next thing you do is iterating over the items by using a `foreach` loop ?

> ```
> var layer1 = layer;
> ```

this isn't necessary at all, it is sufficient to use the `layer` inside linq expression.

---

You should always use braces `{}` for single command `if` statements to make your code less error prone. If you decide to no use them, please don't come back whining that you have a bug you can't find (humour btw.).

---

Integrating the mentioned points will lead to

```
public IList<Layer> GetLayers()
{
    IList<Layer> data = Db.GetLayers();

    IList<Layer> hierarcy = new List<Layer>();

    foreach (var layer in data)
    {

        var sublayers = data.Where(i => i.ParentId == layer.Id && i.ParentId != 0);

        if (sublayers.Any())
        {
            hierarcy.Add(layer);
        }
        foreach (var sublayer in sublayers)
        {
            layer.ChildLayers.Add(sublayer);
        }
    }

    return hierarcy;
}
```

---

> ```
> public class Layer
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public int ParentId { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public IList<Layer> ChildLayers { get; set; }
>
>     public Layer()
>     {
>         ChildLayers = new List<Layer>();
>     }
> }
> ```

You shouldn't expose the `ChildLayers` property setter to the public. If someone comes along setting it to `null` you would be lost.

You should just change it to

```
public IList<Layer> ChildLayers { get; private set; }
```

Otherwise using autoimplemented properties, as long as you don't need validation in the setters , is the way to go.

---

Answer (score 5):

Inside your foreach statement, there is no reason to assign the iterator variable to another variable.   I don't see where it helps you any.  The only place you use that variable is when assigning the `sublayers` variable, and you could just use the iterator to do that anyway.

Comment: This is probably an automatic refactoring. Resharper gives you a warning, when you try to use `foreach` variable directly in a closure, because in some cases it might lead to bugs. It is not the case with this particaular code (since delegate with closure is executed inside foreach loop), but I guess, the warning was too annoying. I know the feeling. :)

Answer (score 5):

There is also a recursive solution:

```
public IList<Layer> GetLayers()
{
    //call it with parentId=0 initially, to get parentless nodes
    return GetChildren(Db.GetLayers(), 0);
}

private IList<Layer> GetChildren(IList<Layer> source, int parentId)
{
    var children = source.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).ToList();
    //GetChildren is called recursively again for every child found
    //and this process repeats until no childs are found for given node, 
    //in which case an empty list is returned
    children.ForEach(x => x.ChildLayers = GetChildren(source, x.Id));
    return children ;
}
```

You should make sure, that you do not have circular dependencies though. Otherwise you might run into `StackOverflowException`.

P.S. You probably need to use two separate classes here. One to represent the data format you use to store your layers in DB:

```
//probably should not be public
public class LayerData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And another class to represent the layer model you are going to work with in your code:

```
public class LayerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LayerModel ParentLayer { get; set; }
    public IList<LayerModel> ChildLayers { get; set; }

    public Layer()
    {
        ChildLayers = new List<Layer>();
    }
}
```

You should not mix them.

Comment: Alright, I've added a few notes.

Answer (score 3):

There is still one thing that I don't like about your code that is not mentioned in the other answers namely the name of the `Db.GetLayers` method. If you are creating something new and your are, you should name the method appropriately like `CreateLayers`. If someone says `GetSomething` it means to me that this something already exists and this method retrievs it.

If this is however a test code you should also construct it to look like a debug/test code, for example:

```
public static class Db
{
    public static IList<Layer> GetLayers()
    {
#if DEBUG
        return CreateTestLayers();
#endif
        reutrn layers form db...

    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static IList<Layer> CreateTestLayers()
    {
        return new List<Layer>
        {
           new Layer{Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Name = "First Layer" },
           new Layer{Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "First SubLayer1" },
           new Layer{Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "First SubLayer2" },
           new Layer{Id = 4, ParentId = 1, Name = "First SubLayer3" },
           new Layer{Id = 5, ParentId = 0, Name = "Second Layer" },
           new Layer{Id = 6, ParentId = 5, Name = "Second SubLayer1" },
           new Layer{Id = 7, ParentId = 5, Name = "Second SubLayer2" },
           new Layer{Id = 8, ParentId = 7, Name = "Sub -3" }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a cleaner way?

Make an intermediate structure that will help group the "flat" list of `Layer`s coming from DB.

---

*Show me your data structures, and I won't usually need your code; it'll be obvious."  - Fred Brooks, The Mythical Man Month

---

```
public Dictionary<int, List<Layer>> rackNstack = new Dictionary<int, List<Layer>>();

public List<Layer> BuildLayerHiArky(List<Layer> flatList) {
    rackNstack.Clear();

    foreach (Layer thing in flatList) {
        if(! rackNstak.ContainsKey(thing.ParentId)
            rackNstack.Add(thing.id, new List<Layer>());

        rackNstack[thing.ParentId].Add(thing);
    }

    List<Layer> allLayers = new Layer();
    Layer oneLayer;

    foreach (var layerList in rackNstack) {
        oneLayer = new Layer();
        oneLayer.Children == layerList.Value;
        oneLayer.Id = layerList.Key
        allLayers.Add(oneLayer);
    }
    return allLayers;
}
```